Cmake: detect if third-party library was compiled in sequential/parallel and link the appropriate libraries
I'm implementing an interface between my C++ code and the linear solver MUMPS. MUMPS can be compiled in parallel (in which case it should be linked against MPI, ScaLAPACK and BLACS) or in sequential (in which case it should be linked against a dummy library provided by the MUMPS distribution).
In my own CMake file, I would like to somehow automatically detect in which mode MUMPS was compiled (parallel or sequential) and link it against the appropriate libraries. Problem: MUMPS declares the exact same symbols in both parallel and sequential modes. So it doesn't look like this process can be automated, but perhaps someone will have a brilliant idea :)
At the moment, I'm using a hard-coded flag:
set(MUMPS_MODE "SEQUENTIAL")
if(${MUMPS_MODE} STREQUAL "PARALLEL")
   add_definitions("-D MUMPS_PARALLEL")
   find_package(MPI REQUIRED)
   list(APPEND LIBRARIES MPI::MPI_CXX MPI::MPI_Fortran)

   find_package(BLACS REQUIRED)
   list(APPEND LIBRARIES ${BLACS_LIBRARY})
   list(APPEND DIRECTORIES ${BLACS_INCLUDE_DIRS})

   find_package(ScaLAPACK REQUIRED)
   list(APPEND LIBRARIES ${ScaLAPACK_LIBRARY})
   list(APPEND DIRECTORIES ${ScaLAPACK_INCLUDE_DIRS})
endif()
if(${MUMPS_MODE} STREQUAL "SEQUENTIAL")
   add_definitions("-D MUMPS_SEQUENTIAL")
   # link dummy parallel library (provided by MUMPS distribution)
   link_to_uno(MUMPS_MPISEQ_LIBRARY ${MUMPS_MPISEQ_LIBRARY})
endif()


Maybe you should have a look at the CheckCSourceCompiles module and its command check_c_source_compiles to check a code in compile and link time (or CheckCSourceRuns if you'd like to also run).
I quickly went through MUMPS documentation, and Section 3.12 "MPI-free version" says:

the calling program should not make use of MP

And here's a question: what will happen if you do? So, if you can write a simple code that can't be compiled, linked, and optionally run with a use of MP, then you actually know that the current MUMPS library was compiled in the sequential mode. At least you can think in that direction.

Thanks, I like the idea! I'll give it a shot.
